# How could I switch scene after a certain amount of time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to switch scene after a few seconds with the code below but it doesn't work, any help would be appreciated.

```
setInterval(change, 5000);
    function change() {

        gotoAndStop(4, "scene 1");
    }
```

Comment: What outcome do you receive? Maybe you should employ `setTimeout` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should store the interval. Then you should change the function's name to a more appropriate, like `changeScene` and then in the function, you must NULL the interval so it won't run the function again, and the last thing is that strings are case sensitive.

```
nextSceneInterval = setInterval(changeScene, 5000);
function changeScene() {
    nextSceneInterval = null;
    gotoAndStop(4, "Scene 1");
}
```

Comment: Although many points in here are correct, the "you must null the interval" is wrong. Preventing the `changeScene` being called by an interval routine is done by calling `clearInterval(nextSceneInterval)` instead. Also, if the scene is needed to be changed just once, using `setTimeout` in place of `setInterval` is better, as you don't need to clear the timeout once it has fired.

Comment: Although I agree, there is no difference in performance, so both methods are acceptable.